# Long app startup times (java), maybe using Slim3 to improve?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm getting close to completing an app engine project (java + jdo), and am a bit worried about startup times. When the app is 'cold', it can take a long time for app engine to load my app (more than 5 seconds) - this is bad because often times the user may just give up after waiting so long.

There's a project called Slim3, which wraps the native datastore - it's supposed to give you startup times of 1 - 3 seconds:
http://sites.google.com/site/slim3appengine/

I don't really want to rely on a third party just to get decent startup times, but I don't think we have any choice. Just wondering how you've dealt with long startup times. I read that as long as your app is getting a hit per 2 minutes or so, then your app is kept resident and this isn't really an issue. That's fair and fine by me (if true).

I don't think the app engine team is working on reducing startup time right now, so wondering what, if anything, we should do to solve this ourselves?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/) is another alternative datastore wrapper that is supposed to be faster than JDO.

According to the [Roadmap](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/roadmap.html), the app engine team is in fact working on this problem, by giving us the ability to reserve instances.  Of course there is not even an estimate of a target date, so it is probably still worth looking into a solution in the meantime.

The other thing you can do is make sure that you have eliminated all of your own code as a startup bottleneck.  Are you sure it is just the JDO code that is taking a long time?  Are there any initialization tasks you can defer until later, to spread the cost of the first hit?

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure how to profile startup time - how can we tell which components are taking how much time to init - and then if objectify/slim3 would help? I'm not using any 3rd party libraries, just plain gae java and the jdo annotations. Not using GWT either.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, in Japanese App Engine community, Slim3 is a defacto standard for accessing to Datastore - over 50% of users on my Twitter TL are using it for profuction service. It's much faster than JDO for both spin-up time and query speed (as fast as low level API), and easier to build a query by utilizing Java/Eclipse's type system.

Thanks,

Kaz